# Sqlalchemy- Create Amazon S3 Presigned URL

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, boto3

I am trying to create an S3 presigned URL so that people can have temporary access to the files stored in a S3 bucket.

I have a function like this to create the url:

```
def create_presigned_url(file_name):
        """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object
            return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
        """
        
        bucket_name = 'mybucket'
        object_name = 'pdfs/{}'.format(file_name)
        expiration = 3600
        # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
        try:
            response = bucket_resource.generate_presigned_url(
                "get_object",
                Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": object_name},
                ExpiresIn=expiration,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return None
    
        # The response contains the presigned URL
        return response
```

Now I want to apply this url to the table EnrollmentFormData which is defined below:

```
class EnrollmentFormData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'enrollment_form_data'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    employee_number = db.Column(db.String(12),nullable=False)
    department_code = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
    sign_image = db.Column(db.BLOB, nullable=False)
    aws_path = db.Column(db.String(2083), nullable=False)
    file_name = db.Column(db.String(2083), nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=lambda: 
    datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York")))
```

I have tried two things:

First, I tried to pass the column name as a param of the function:

```
 query = db.session.query(
        EnrollmentFormData.id,
        create_presigned_url(EnrollmentFormData.file_name),
        EnrollmentFormData.timestamp
    ).all()
```

This didn't work maybe because the function is unable to work with a SqlAlchemy type.

Then I tried with the `@hybrid_property`

```
class EnrollmentFormData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'enrollment_form_data'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    employee_number = db.Column(db.String(12),nullable=False)
    department_code = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
    sign_image = db.Column(db.BLOB, nullable=False)
    aws_path = db.Column(db.String(2083), nullable=False)
    file_name = db.Column(db.String(2083), nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York")))
    
    
    @hybrid_property
    def create_presigned_url(self):
        """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object
            return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
        """
        
        bucket_name = 'myBucket'
        object_name = 'pdfs/{}'.format(self.file_name)
        expiration = 3600
        # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
        try:
            response = bucket_resource.generate_presigned_url(
                "get_object",
                Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": object_name},
                ExpiresIn=expiration,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return None
    
        # The response contains the presigned URL
        return response
    
    @create_presigned_url.expression
    def create_presigned_url(self):
        """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object
            return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
        """
        
        bucket_name = 'myBucket'
        object_name = 'pdfs/{}'.format(self.file_name)
        expiration = 3600
        # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
        try:
            response = bucket_resource.generate_presigned_url(
                "get_object",
                Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": object_name},
                ExpiresIn=expiration,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
    
        # The response contains the presigned URL
        return response

#query

query = db.session.query(
        EnrollmentFormData.id,
        EnrollmentFormData.create_presigned_url,
        EnrollmentFormData.timestamp,
    )
```

The above doesn't work either

The error both gives is:

```
SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got ''
```

Sorry can't paste the whole thing because I don't want to give away access keys.

Can anyone help how to get it done?

Comment: Are you needing to store the generated url to the DB, or just be able to provide it on demand?

Comment: Provide it on demand. Can I create my own custom SQL func for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're going to provide a custom SQL func you'll want to avoid using the [.expression modifier](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) and stay with instance-level methods.

```py
    @hybrid_property
    def create_presigned_url(self):
        """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object
            return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
        """
        
        bucket_name = 'myBucket'
        object_name = 'pdfs/{}'.format(self.file_name)
        expiration = 3600
        # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
        try:
            response = bucket_resource.generate_presigned_url(
                "get_object",
                Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": object_name},
                ExpiresIn=expiration,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return None
    
        # The response contains the presigned URL
        return response
```

To use this you would want to operate at the instance level, not the class level. So your query is for the instance:

```py
instance = db.session.query(EnrollmentFormData).filter(EnrollmentFormData.id==1).first()
print(instance.create_presigned_url)

#or
instance = db.session.query(EnrollmentFormData).get(1)
print(instance.create_presigned_url)

#or
print([x.create_presigned_url for x in db.session.query(EnrollmentFormData).all()]
```

Comment: Is there any way to use it at the class level?

Comment: I think this is the way to call it ```instance.create_presigned_url``` could you please edit your answer?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry -- it's a property

Comment: @kerasbaz, this does not load hybrid_property eagerly. `instance` doesn't get value of `create_presigned_url` unless we access it first time. How can we eager load.